# How can I implement a drag and drop file/folder upload that is recursive?

Tags: java, file-upload

I am looking for some way to implement a drop box for files and folders to be uploaded to the site. I found one from [rad inks](http://www.radinks.com/upload/), but it only supports multiple files.

Does anyone know about something like this that supports folder uploading?

The website itself is based on PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with an applet, from the same guys you were looking:

http://www.radinks.com/upload/folder.php

Demo:
http://www.radinks.com/upload/applet.php

Comment: I noticed that but I'm looking for something that's free or either info on how this can be done.

Comment: The Lite edition is free and I think it supports what you want. Anyway, dude, the Rad Upload is $49 and the Rad Upload Plus is $69, which is WAY CHEAPER than what you are going to spend doing it yourself. Even your research time will cost you more!

Comment: This is something that might be used for many website so we're not talking about just $49. Still I think it's something worth taking a look at.

Comment: oh, I see. Yeah, at least take a look at the lite edition to check if the functionality is included. If not, you can always decompile the applet to see how they do it ;)  (which is illegal, of course)